# Unique URI error

Tags: entry, error-message, entry-slug

I am getting the following error when trying to save a structured entry:

```
Could not generate a unique URI based on the URI format.
```

Title of entry is: Hells Gate Mud Bath & Spa

Slug: `hells-gate-mud-bath-spa`

The entry title is 100% unique also. Any ideas what is causing this and what the fix may be?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the error was because {slug} was missing from the Section Setting: Entry URI Format